# how to join two ResultSets from oracle queries in java

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee

Is it possible to join two ResultSets like join two tables in Java-oracle programming?  I am writing a java program which querys two different oracle databases(the databases are physically in different locations). In the program, sql1 returns ResultSet ret1;sql2 returns ResultSet ret2.   Suppose ret1  has the following data:

```
Id   item
------------
1   item1
2   item 2
3   item 3
.........
```

Ret2 has the following data

```
Id  info
---------
1  info1
2  info2
…
```

I need result like this

```
Id item info
----------------------
1   item1 info1
2   item2  info2
```

Can I do something like this in java:

```
Select ret1.id,ret1.item,ret2,info from ret1, ret2 where ret1.id=ret2.id
```

I know I can loop from ret1 and get the id then get info from ret2; I am wondering if there is a fast way like join two tables to join two ResultSets without looping? Actually these two results both have half million rows. Thank you!

Comment: do you have any dblinks setup between the 2 databases?

Comment: no, I don't have dblinks. I actually need to use jdbc to connect two databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dblink is not allowed to create due to permission issue. I finally find another solution. Here is what I am doing: I get resultset ret1 then using:

```
while (ret1.next()) { 
  get id from ret1, 
  query  info from another database;
  bla,bla,...
}
....
```

The performance is much better than getting two resultsets then looping one inside another...

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this:

```
 SELECT ret1.id,ret1.item,ret2.info
FROM ret1
RIGHT JOIN ret2 
ON ret1.id=ret2.id;
```

[Sql Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae35e/1)

**EDIT:**

If the two ResultSets are from the same database then why not combine them during the retrieval by using union; e.g.

```
select A, B
from C
union
select A, B
from D
```

Comment: can I do this in Java? both ret1 and ret2 are ResultSet type. thank you!

Comment: are you retriving both the resultsets from the same database..?

Comment: no, the results are from two different databases which are physically located in different places.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is loop through both the result sets `ret1` and `ret2` in Java and compare  `id` in both of them and then store the result in a multi dimensional array, something like-

```
  while (ret1.next()) {
        int id1 = rs.getInt("ID"); 
        while (ret2.next()){
               int id2 = rs.getInt("ID");
               if ( id1 == id2 )
               ...  
               ...
        }
  }
```

And as others say, a better approach will be to use `dblinks`. And as Tom Kyte says-

> the less code you write, the less bugs you create
>   the more code you write, the more bugs you create
>   write less code, suffer less bugs
>   write more code, suffer more bugs

Comment: I can see that homegrown nested loop code taking forever on 2 large sets, I agree that dblinks are much preferred (let the db do the heavy data work, leave the pretty/light work to java ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest and more effective solution is to have a dblink from one database to the other and do the join in the query. Otherwise you have to loop through both resultsets.

Answer (score 0):

Is your intended output to some type of bean or other java data structure? 
Assuming it is and you are using [commons dbutils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/) to fill a javabean. 
I would create a list of beans of type ret1 using [BeanListHandler](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/handlers/BeanListHandler.html), and then use a [BeanMapHandler](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/handlers/BeanMapHandler.html) on ret2 to get a map of beans with the map key as the id from ret2. 
Then as you are looping throught ret1, you can access the values in ret2 by the id of ret1. 
 
Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [DB Link](http://psoug.org/reference/db_link.html) for your requirement.

Or you can try using an materialized view.